# Php singleton class :PDO Query result as array in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working small php project and i am using singleton database class from this [repo](https://gist.github.com/skhani/5aebd11015881fb3d288)

The problem is i can't get query result as array value.Here is my code

**Core.php**

```
class Core extends Database
{

    public static function run($sql)
    {
        return parent::getInstance()->getConnection()->query($sql);
    }
    public function getUniversities()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `adm_universities`';
        return Core::run($sql);
    }
}


 //get the data from db 
    $result=Core::getUniversities();
   print_r($result);
```

But the `PDOStatement Object` returns only the `queryString` not the result array.
what's wrong with this code?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation on the link that leads nowhere

Comment: I think my query is didn't executed here

Comment: `Core::getUniversities()` means that your method is static. But it is not. Your code must return error not the string or array now.

Comment: You are not using the class properly. See the repo example coded in the `Post` class inside the downloaded code of that repo

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `foreach` loop over PDOStatement or get a conventional array from it using `fetchAll()` method.

```
foreach ($result as $row) ...
// or
$data = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
```

Note that this singleton class makes very little sense as it doesn't support prepared statements.

Also, there should be no `getUniversities()` in the Core class. That's bizarre thing for the OOP.

Comment: Worth pointing that it's also "instantiable", which defeats singleton nature.

Comment: i cant understand this `there should be no getUniversities() in the Core class`

Answer (score -1):

You have not used fetch or fetchall or find it seems.
Check the pdo manual properly.

You have to execute the query and then you have to use result functions to get the result array

Comment: He's extending a class.